# How to use activitymiddleware if activities of type event are sent twice by BotFramework

Tags: botframework, web-chat

To be able to hide the sendBox in a webchat client, my bot logic sends an event to tell the client to hide the sendbox. In the client I am using middleware to catch this event and hide or show the sendBox. In the console, i see that every event I sent from the bot, Is handled by the middleware twice resulting in unexpected behavior. Anyone an idea how to deal with this?

In my bot-code (a waterfall dialogue)

DialogueStep 1.

```
const hideSendBox =
  {
     name: 'hideSendBox',
     type: 'event'
  };
await stepContext.context.sendActivity(hideSendBox);
return await stepContext.prompt(PROMPT_THAT_DOES_NOT_NEED_SENDBOX, '');
```

and DialogueStep 2.

```
const showSendBox =
  {
     name: 'showSendBox',
     type: 'event'
  };
await stepContext.context.sendActivity(showSendBox);
return await stepContext.prompt(PROMPT_THAT_DOES_NEED_SENDBOX, '');
```

and

DialogueStep 3.

```
return await stepContext.prompt(PROMPT_THAT_DOES_NEED_SENDBOX, '');
```

In my webchat code

```
const activityMiddleware = () => next => ({ activity, nextVisibleActivity, ...otherArgs }) => {
    const { name, type } = activity;
    if (type === 'event') {console.log(activity)};
    if (type === 'event' && name === 'hideSendBox') {
      document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      return () => <Component1 activity={activity} nextVisibleActivity={nextVisibleActivity} />;
    } else if (type === 'event' && name === 'showSendBox') {
      document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
      return () => <Component2 activity={activity} nextVisibleActivity={nextVisibleActivity} />;
    }
    else {
      return next({ activity, nextVisibleActivity, ...otherArgs });
    }
  };
```

The result:

1. after first activity is sent (hideSendbox), the activity middleware gets the event and sendBox is hidden
2. after second activity is sent (showSendbox), the activity middleware gets the second event (sendBox will be show) and after that, the first event again. As a result, the sendBox is hidden again.
3. as soon as the conversation continues and other activities are sent by the bot), the middleware gets the second event again and the sendbox is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `activityMiddleware`, per the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/API.md), are intended for "adding new DOM components into the currently existing DOM of activities". Using this middleware would be incorrect for what you are trying to do.

Instead, you should pass this in thru Web Chat's store. When set up as below, the send box is hidden and displayed per the event passed in.

*Please note:* the Web Chat team strongly discourages making direct changes to the DOM, if it can be avoided. By altering the DOM directly you open yourself up for possible breaking changes should a Web Chat component get overhauled in the future.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
    const { activity } = action.payload;
    if (activity.type === 'event') {
      if (activity.name === 'hideSendBox') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      } else if (activity.name === 'showSendBox') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  }
} );
```

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: tnx. that helped. Just don;t like that I have to implement this password 'logic' in a store and an activity middleware ;-)